# How to run a function automatically when it gets imported - Python

Tags: python-3.x

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if it is possible to run a function automatically when it gets imported.

For example:

main.py

```
from myMod import hello_world
```

myMod.py

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello World from %s" % __name__)
```

This is the output that I want to see when I run main.py:

```
Hello World from main.py
```

I would also like to keep `hello_world` as a function.

Comment: Just add `hello_world()` at the bottom of `myMod.py`, all statements within a module are executed when imported.

Comment: `hello_world` doesn't know about main.py. It will print `Hello world from myMod`   that is, the `__name__` in its module namespace. `main.py` would not only have to call the function, it would have to pass its `__name__` to the function. Worse, for top level scripts, `__name__` is `__main__`, not the name of the .py file.